# SMTP cannot send outgoing mail to google and yahoo

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, router, smtp

I installed the ubuntu server 14.04 lts. I have opened port of 465 and 587 on /etc/postfix/main.cf and master.cf. SMTP cannot send outgoing mail to google and yahoo. but it received outside mail from google and yahoo.  I registered no-ip website. I set port forward on my router.

Let me know how to right configuration SMTP and is also right port forward on the router.

Thanks

Everybody.

Comment: Does it send to providers other than google or yahoo or any outgoing mail at all. I would also have to consider anti spam filtering on google and yahoo could be happening.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I consider anti spam filtering that it should be impossibile. because we received other outside email. I also send to other email such as hotmail, 163, 126 and our company email. it cannot send out that mail account. The message is showing time out.        Would you tell how to do configuration SMTP detail?

Comment: we received google message "connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::1b]:25: Network is unreachable" how to solve? thanks!